# DISTINCT AND UNION keywords cause timeout exception in iDB2Command

Tags: sql, db2, oledb, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to query some date from DB2/IBM AS400. for this purpose I've tested theses two libraries: Oledb and iDB2Command that iDB2Command is released by IBM in their iSerires package for .Net

when I execute the following command with iDB2Command, I get a command timeout exception:

```
        using (iDB2Connection connection = new iDB2Connection("DATA SOURCE=0.0.0.0;USER ID=TEST;PASSWORD=TEST;CheckConnectionOnOpen=true;EnablePreFetch=false;"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM LIB.Table1", connection);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            iDB2DataAdapter da = new iDB2DataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
```

But when I use Oledb to execute the same query there is no problem and the query will be execute and returns some data.this is while if I remove "DISTINCT" keyword, the query will be executed with iDB2Command too. Similar to this problem is exists for UNION keywords and nested queries.

I even checked and config theses things, but the problem was not solved:

- Increase QRYTIMLMT using CHGQRYA command
- Uncheck "Allow Query Timeout" in "Odbc Datasource Administrator" for iSeries DSN.

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried changing the CommandTimeout property in you .Net code?

Comment: My questition is that why some commands work with oledb but not with IBM's iDB2Command? 
yes, if you look at my code I've set timeout to 0

Comment: I'm just saying select distinct * something wrong in your design.  Who makes a table that doesn't have unique key or some key.  With that said I thinks its something like "Read uncommitted" or read *change will tell the database you just want a point in time and you don't care about any uncomitted  transactions.